# parallel::makeCluster stops working after each process on a node reaches 182.6 MB RAM

Tags: r, parallel-processing, evolutionary-algorithm

When I create a cluster using **`parallel::makeCluster`**, the CPU kicks in on the other nodes until the RAM on each process of the node hits **`182.6 [MB]`**. At that point, the nodes stop computing anything, leaving only the master to do computations.

Any idea how I could troubleshoot this?

This is the exact code I'm using to invoke the clusters:

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(c(rep("localhost", 8), rep("10.0.0.101", 8)))
```

I am using the cluster in **`rgenoud::genoud`** if that helps to explain the issue.

Thanks!